# Animation Issues with two views

Tags: ios, swift

I have an animation where when I press on the `UIButton` the button's dimensions are cut in half, and the button is moved further to the left hand side of the view. While the button is animating, a `UITextField` which is off of the view, and unable to be seen originally, is transformed left onto the view. However, when I press on the `UITextField` to begin typing, the  button goes back to it's original position, the position set before the animation started, and the button's dimensions stay the same. But the `UITextField` disappears off of the view. How can I make it so that the `UIButton` stays in its spot on the left hand side, and keep the `UITextField` from disappearing. I've used the following code:

```
@IBAction func joinCircleButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let button = sender as UIButton
    joinTextField.frame.origin.x=500
    joinTextField.frame.origin.y=100
    if (button.frame.origin.x - 75>0){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations:{
        button.frame = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x - 125, button.frame.origin.y,button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height)
        button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
        self.joinTextField.frame=CGRectMake(self.joinTextField.frame.origin.x - 325, self.joinTextField.frame.origin.y,self.joinTextField.frame.size.width, self.joinTextField.frame.size.height)

    })
    }
}
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
    joinTextField.center = CGPointMake(joinTextField.frame.origin.x-500, joinTextField.frame.origin.y)


}
```

Comment: Not answering your question really, but if you are coding with swift, why not use its closure-as-last-parameter rule and call the animation function like this: `UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { //some code... }`

Comment: @AvielGross I am new with animations, and thats the code I was found, I didn't think to change it.

Comment: Still looking for answers...

Comment: Answered already at [this question herein][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772126/textfield-disapearing/27772340#27772340